# How do i implement a data filled dropdown list with Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 6, or really just Angular period. I am wanting to place a drop down list on my page which will be populated with values I get from a JSON request else where. How would I go about accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 // http request with your server data.
 options$ = this.yourHttpService.getOptions(API);  // returns an Observable
```

Assume the JSON format is(we will invoke option.value int HTML):

```
{
    value: 'Option1',
    otherValue: '....'
}
```

In your html file, populate the options with `async`:

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="yourOption" id="category">
       <option value="" disabled selected>>select an option</option>
       <option *ngFor="let option of options$ | async" [value]="option.value">{item.category}}</option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data that needs to be put in the dropdown list is actually an array:

```
 myData = {data: [v1, v2, v3, v4]};
```

In your `component.html`

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let eachVal of myData['data']>
          {{eachVal}}
  </option>
</select>
```

should do the trick.

Since you do not provide your code snippet, I have a [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-workflow-test) that uses `select` and `option` tags with Angular. Have a look at them.